# Google Analytics for iOS send tracking only when WiFi is available, otherwise to Cache

Tags: android, ios, caching, google-analytics

I searched for similar posts here but found no answer, so mark this duplicate if there is one I didn't find.
So my question is: I'm using Google Analytics on both android and iOS, and both are facing the same problem. I wanted GA only to send tracking when WiFi is available, and this could be easily done by checking the net status. But now I want GA to cache the events/screens when no WiFi is available and send it later when Wifi available.

I found in document the cache is only written when no internet is available, so what I want to ask is actually: is there a way to force GA cache the tracking even when 3G is available? didn't find such method in SDK.

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement this in iOS app you might want to download [this Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or (I prefer) [this handy github project](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

If you choose second way, you just need to create and configure Reachability class instance at startup like this

```
// disable automatic sending of statistics 
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;

Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reach){
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20; 

    // you also may send cached statistics right on WiFi appear
    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reach) {
    // disable automatic upload, this will force GAI to cache all hits 
    // until you call dispatch or set dispatchInterval
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
};
```